# How to fix this ISeries interface implementation in Class1?

Tags: c#, interface

I am developing a series of numbers starting from Setstart(2) function from ISeries interface. I tried to implement this interface in Class1 but it threw an error to me. And I am getting stuck at this error and not been able to figure out to fix this. What am I missing? Please help

I tried to make all functions in the interface public
I tried to remove public access specifier from interface

```
public interface ISeries {
    void Setstart (int a);
    int GetNext ();
    void Reset ();
}

class Class1 : ISeries {

    int val;
    void Setstart (int a) {
        val = a;
    }

    int GetNext () {
        return val++;
    }

    void Reset () {
        val = 0;
    }

    static void Main () {
        Class1 c = new Class1 ();
        c.Setstart (2);
        Console.WriteLine (c.GetNext ());
        c.Reset ();
        Console.WriteLine ();
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be 3 and 0 error is being generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should try something like this.

Because you have to play with one variable so you have to make use of `ref` `keyword in this case.

and also you have to mark all the method inside a `class` as a `public` otherwise you were not be able to access those method inside `main`

**Code:**

```
using System;

namespace StackoverflowProblem
{
    public interface ISeries
    {
        void Setstart(ref int value);
        int GetNext(ref int value);
        void Reset(ref int value);
    }

    public class Class1 : ISeries
    {
        public int val { get; set; }

        public void Setstart(ref int value)
        {
            this.val = value;
        }

        public int GetNext(ref int value)
        {
            value = value + 1;
            this.val = value;

            return this.val;
        }

        public void Reset(ref int value)
        {
            // Resetting val.
            value = 0;
            this.val = value;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 c = new Class1();

            int value = 2;
            c.Setstart(ref value);

            Console.WriteLine(" " + c.GetNext(ref value));

            c.Reset(ref value);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: All these are unnecessary to make that simple program work. this is an overkill. no need to make them reference members since he is accessing the variable on root scope, he is not passing it as an argument to the function.

Comment: @Vilsad P P : Every Problem have multiple solution so i presented my solution in this way and its work fine according to the the Question expectation....So please remove the DownVote because of no any specific reason...

Comment: i am not saying your solution will not work, i was saying its an overkill for such a simple issue. that was the reason for my down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your methods `public` to be accessible outside from class which is missing other than that your code looks fine.

You need to make all the 3 methods public as per your scenario like :

```
public void Setstart (int a) {
```

and you will need to first add 1 and then return to get 3 as output as `val++` will return the current value and then increment it by 1:

```
public int GetNext () {

        // return val++; // Post increment will not work according to question.
        val = val + 1;
        return val;
    }
```

Your class with complete implementation of Interface would be like following:

```
public class Class1 : ISeries {

    int val;
    public void Setstart (int a) {
        val = a;
    }

    public int GetNext () {
        val = val + 1;
        return val;
    }

    public void Reset () {
        val = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: you will still get 2 as output

Answer (score 0):

val++ will incriment after returning the current value, ++val will increment first then return the value, you should now get 3, also make it proper scoped to access the methods from outside

```
class Class1 : ISeries {

int val;
public void Setstart (int a) {
    val = a;
}

public int GetNext () {
    return ++val;
}

public void Reset () {
    val = 0;
}

static void Main () {

    Class1 c = new Class1();
    c.Setstart(2);
    Console.WriteLine (c.GetNext());
    c.Reset();
    Console.WriteLine ("");
}
```

}

Comment: with respect to your answer...the output is 2 but the expected output is three...Please read the Question carefully...

Comment: check this out, my answer is correct, it will print 3 https://dotnetfiddle.net/VPgSY0

Comment: @Rehan.S please check the fiddle result and kindly remove your down vote.